# How can I count the amount of text lines there are in HTML using NPM jsdom?

Tags: javascript, html, npm

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var html = "<p>line 1</p><p>another line</p><p>line 3</p><script>//not a line</script><p>last line</p>"
let dom = new JSDOM(html)
```

How could I use the dom variable and count how many text lines the HTML uses? Based on the html variable, I would expect to receive a count of 4. I'm not concerned about text-overflow; imagine the text will always fit.

Something like counting the number of line breaks in document.body.innerText from Google Chrome is nice. Though this isn't possible with jsdom.

Comment: The DOM structure is not responsible for the display itself. What if the browser width is not as wide as you think? What if someone decided to style the `<p>` element as inline instead of block?

Comment: document.body.innerText seems to account for everything pretty well. Though that isn't an option with NPM jsdom. innerText seems to ignore the screen width. I was wondering if there's some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with plain javascript. I don't know if this is any help as you mentioned NPM jsdom...

```js
        function getLineCount(el) {
            var characters = el.textContent.split('');
            el.textContent = '';
            var lastRegisteredTextHeight = 0;
            var lines = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
                el.textContent += characters[i];
                currentTextHeight = el.offsetHeight;
                if (currentTextHeight > lastRegisteredTextHeight) {
                    lines++;
                    lastRegisteredTextHeight = currentTextHeight;
                }
            }
            return lines;
        }

        var lineCount = getLineCount(document.querySelector('h1'));
        console.log(lineCount);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```